# GraphQL query returns null data

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

My schema looks like this

[image: SchemaDesc]

[image: Schema]

And my server setup looks like this
[image: Server Setup]

When I perform a Query operation or Mutation Operation It works well, but when I perform a subscription operation, it shows that the data is null. Why is this happening?

[image: GraphiQL result]

Comment: Maybe you need to await the return of subscribe. subscribe: async (parent, args,...) => {... return await pubSub.asyncIterator}

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it, but it didn't work.